# Rails redirected url is giving 302 instead of 301 status after redirecting the old url to new url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just implemented `friendly_id` on the rails application. I pushed the changes to production. Earlier the url used to be:

`https://example.com/search?category_id=1`.

After implementing `friendly_id` it is like this

`https://example.com/search?category_id=name`

My **controller** code for redirecting old url to new url is as follows:

```
if params[:category_id].present? and params[:category_id].to_s !~ /\D/
       category = Category.find_by_id(params[:category_id])
       return redirect_to search_equipments_path(request.query_parameters.merge(category_id: category.slug)) if category.present?
```

When testers started testing it SEO optimisation, they found that the url redirection is generating a weird status. Like it is going from **302** -> **301**  -> **200** . Where as it should be generating a **301** status. How can fix this ? How can I make it generate a **301** status ?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `status` option with a `redirect_to` e.g.

```
redirect_to search_equipments_path(request.query_parameters.merge(category_id: category.slug)), status: 301 if category.present?
```

Read more [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/redirect_to)

Also, I am curious why do you need `return` there? If you really need, I think correct syntax should be `redirect_to and return` e.g.

```
if params[:category_id].to_s !~ /\D/ && Category.find_by_id(params[:category_id])
   redirect_to search_equipments_path(request.query_parameters.merge(category_id: category.slug)) and return
end
```